# Can I make a bracha on smelling roses that may be orla?

Tags: blessing, smell, orla-revai, besamim-spices

Roses are considered "Atzei Besamim" so does orla apply to them and if so do I make a bracha on smelling orla roses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is Orla only for a tree that was planted for eating.

See Rash Orla 1.1

> פטור מן הערלה. כדדריש בירושלמי (הלכה א) (ויקרא יט) ונטעתם כל עץ מאכל את שהוא למאכל חייב

So, because roses are generally not cultivated for eating, there is no din Orla and you can smell their perfume.

Ruled in SA YD 294.1

> הנוטע עץ מאכל מונה לו ג' שנים מעת נטיעתו וכל הפירות שיהיו בו בתוך ג' שנים אסורין בהנאה לעולם בין עיקר הפרי בין הגרעינים בין הקליפות