# Can one smell orla tree blossoms?

Tags: halacha, blessing, trees, smell, orla-revai

Follow-up to [Can I make a bracha on smelling roses that may be orla?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101701/)

As per [SA YD 294:1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/101703/), orla only applies to trees which were planted for eating.

Can one smell the blossoms of a tree planted for fruit within the tree’s first three years? Can one make a Bracha on this smell?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37624/), it would seem that this is permitted.

> The Radbaz ([Shu"t
>   1:44](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1952&pgnum=24))
>   discusses this topic and rules that, if the tree was not planted for
>   its fruits or if only the blossoms are present and the fruit has not
>   yet grown, the fragrance is permitted (i.e. there is no problem of
>   *orlah* preventing enjoyment of the fragrance):
>
> > כללא דמלתא אין לך דבר של ערלה שיהיה אסור להריח בו אלא אילן הנטוע לפירות מאכל ומריח בפירות עצמו אפילו בעודם בוסר ולא בעודם סמדר
>
> The Chida ([*Birkei Yosef* YD
>   294:13](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7670&st=&pgnum=146))
>   agrees with this ruling. This topic is also discussed at length by
>   Rabbi Pinchas Zabichi ([*Ateret Paz* I, YD
>   16](http://www.bsd-paz.org/Texts/AteretPaz_v2_Yore_Dayah/html/E7ECF75FE05FEBF8EA5FE15FE9E5F8E45FE3F2E45FF1E9EEEF5FE8E65FE7ECF75FE0.htm)).

Comment: The original question is not a duplicate of this one, as one talks about inedible trees and the other about edible ones.

Comment: It's pretty much an explicit mishnah https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Orlah.1.7.  The only extra information needed is we don't pasken like R' Yosi.  And on that note https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5039/revisions

Comment: הסמדר - הוא הפרח שממנו יצא הבוסר. אבל הבוסר עצמו הכל מודים שהוא פרי יח    Mishna orla 1.7  Bartenura

Comment: @Heshy Shows you how much I need to chazer over orlah. :)

Comment: in perush harambam ואמר בספרא פריו פרט לעלים ולולבים ולמי גפנים וסמדר: